# Why would "I searched everywhere but couldn't find the answer" be kept in a question?

Tags: discussion, question-quality, suggested-edit

Why keep some useless noise in a question?

For sure, we don't accept taglines as ruled by: *[Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)*.

But why keep stuff **similar** to:

> "I searched everywhere but couldn't find the answer"

See [this edit suggestion](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/127442) rejected by two high reputation users.

It doesn't add value to see if the OP knew the answer or not at the time of the post, so why keep it?

Comment: Are you asking about that specific rejected edit, or those types of phrases in general? If the latter, this would probably be better suited for Main Meta.

Comment: @Skooba I'm asking SciFi policy specifically. On some other communities, like Stack Overflow, the edit would have been welcomed.

Answer (score 10):

The downvote tooltip states:

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful

The edit in question was removing:

> I've searched both google and the site but looks like this hasn't been asked yet.

Whilst not terribly informative it is telling us what research they have already done and is also hinting at the question not being a duplicate. Of course the OP could be lying but it does mean that the likelihood for a duplicate is less.

---

On the general note of the hypothetical case of what you want to edit out;

> "*I searched everywhere but couldn't find the answer*"

This isn't useful as it gives us no information and if I had seen that being edited out of a post I would have approved it. It comes down to a case by case basis and exactly what the comment you are removing is.

Comment: Saying "_I've searched_" isn't the definition of a research effort. A research effort is in the lines of "_according to [this], we have [that] fact_".

Comment: @Cœur Well this is where site culture comes into play. On SO I'd have nuked that line, here I keep it cos even though it isn't particularly helpful it gives us some information.

Comment: FWIW I would have rejected that edit for the first reason you sighted.